# Output formatting of a list

Tags: python, os.walk, output-formatting

Have a piece of code in python :

```
print (sorted([(r,len(f)) for r,d,f in os.walk(directory_path)],key=lambda x : x[1],reverse = True))
```

which gives output like :

```
[('/etc/ssl/certs', 595), ('/etc/alternatives', 109), ('/etc/', 73), ('/etc/init.d', 52),('/etc/dovecot/conf.d', 27)]
```

I want something like (without storing it to a variable):

```
('/etc/ssl/certs', 595)
('/etc/alternatives', 109)
('/etc/', 73)
('/etc/init.d', 52)
('/etc/dovecot/conf.d', 27)]
```

Comment: just use pprint

Answer (score 1):

using [pprint](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pprint.html#pprint.pprint)

```
import pprint
pprint.pprint(sorted([(r,len(f)) for r,d,f in os.walk(directory_path)],key=lambda x : x[1],reverse = True))

pprint.pprint([('/etc/ssl/certs', 595), ('/etc/alternatives', 109), ('/etc/', 73), ('/etc/init.d', 52),('/etc/dovecot/conf.d', 27)])
# [('/etc/ssl/certs', 595),
#  ('/etc/alternatives', 109),
#  ('/etc/', 73),
#  ('/etc/init.d', 52),
#  ('/etc/dovecot/conf.d', 27)]
```

Answer (score -1):

have you ever tried something like that ?

```
[print(str(x)) for x in sorted([(r,len(f)) for r,d,f in os.walk(directory_path)],key=lambda x : x[1],reverse = True)]
```